# How to get the count of two number combination from the list

Tags: python

In Python I have a list as below.

```
MyList = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,3], [1,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[2,2]]
```

I need to get the combination count as below

```
[1,2] = 3 
[2,3] = 1
[1,3]= 1
[2,2] = 2
[3,3] = 1
```

I tried using combination util but it doesn't work. Please advice if there is efficient way to perform the count.

```
from collections import Counter
MyList = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,3], [1,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[2,2]]
c = Counter(MyList)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work,

```
from collections import Counter
MyList = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,3], [1,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[2,2]]
c = Counter([tuple(el) for el in MyList])
c
```

---

**Output:**

```
Counter({(1, 2): 3, (2, 3): 1, (1, 3): 1, (2, 2): 2, (3, 3): 1})
```

Converting inner elements to tuple, to make it hashable.

When there is an unhashable data structure like `list` in your case, it will become hard to find unique values because it's hard to guarantee that the data inside `sub list` won't change. (In your case with a tuple you can guarantee that the data inside the tuple won't change).

Answer (score 1):

use tuple

```
from collections import Counter
kkk = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,3], [1,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[2,2]]
kkk = [tuple(i) for i in kkk]
c = Counter(kkk)
c
```

result

`Counter({(1, 2): 3, (2, 3): 1, (1, 3): 1, (2, 2): 2, (3, 3): 1})`

Comment: why would you name it kkk